# Clearing ComboBox on Workbook_Open

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I have following code in the `Workbook_Open` event handler:

```
   Sheet1.ComboBox1.Clear
   Sheet1.ComboBox2.Clear

   Set Rng = Sheet2.Range("A3", Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
   With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   For Each cel In Rng
   If Not .exists(cel.Value) Then
        .Add cel.Value, Nothing
    End If

 Sheet1.ComboBox1.List = .keys
```

My issue is that it is not clearing `ComboBox1` on `Workbook_Open` and shows earlier selected values.

I also used following

```
     Sheet1.ComboBox1.ListIndex = -1 ' instead of sheet1.combobox1.clear
     Sheet1.ComboBox2.ListIndex = -1 ' instead of sheet1.combobox2.clear
```

But the problem remains.

Can anyone suggest a solution? Thanks in advance to.

Answer (score 0):

I made some corrections to you code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim cel As Range

    Sheet1.ComboBox1.Clear
    Sheet1.ComboBox2.Clear

    Set Rng = Sheet2.Range("A3", Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

        For Each cel In Rng
            If Not .exists(cel.Value) Then
                .Add cel.Value, Nothing
            End If
        Next cel

        Sheet1.ComboBox1.List = .keys

    End With

End Sub
```

If I manually add an item to `ComboBox` and save the workbook, close the workbook, then re-open the workbook then the list reverts to a distinct list from `Sheet2`.

Can you try it?